# How to correctly compare values in 2 different lists?

Tags: python, excel, list, csv, compare

I've got a folder full of excel files. The aim is to record all files in the folder, open each file, run analysis on it, record which files have been analyzed, continue until all files in folder have been analyzed. My approach has been to create 2 lists and 1 csv excel files, one list to record all the files in the folder (datafile list), the second is to record which files have been analysed already so that the program wouldn't re-do unecessery files (Analysed list and csv for memory). I'm having trouble comparing the 2 lists due to formatting issues that I can't seem to fix.

Problem: When printing the datafile list, I'm getting formatting that I'm happy with such as:

```
# Fill Datafile list
for file in listdir(r'DataPath'):
    if file.endswith("Data.xlsx"):  # Look for datafiles
        Datafile_list.append(file)  # Add filename to list
        i = i+1
    print("Datafile list: ", Datafile_list, "\n", "Number of datafiles: ", i)

    >>> Datafile list:  ['Ant_10_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_11_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_12_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_13_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_14_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_15_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_17_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_18_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_19_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_1_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_20_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_21_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_22_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_23_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_25_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_26_(F6)_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_27_(E1)_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_2_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_3_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_4_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_5_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_6_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_7_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_8_Data.xlsx', 'Ant_9_Data.xlsx'] 
    >>> Number of datafiles:  25
```

When printing analysed list which is recorded in an excel csv list: I'm getting formatting with extra quotations and extra square brackets which messes up with the comparison.

```
# fill in analysed list
with open(r'\Analysed_list.csv', 'r', newline='') as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    Analysed_list = list(reader)
    print("Analysed List:", Analysed_list)
>>> Analysed List: [["['Ant_10_Data.xlsx'", " 'Ant_11_Data.xlsx'", " 'Ant_12_Data.xlsx'"], ['Test', '', '']]
```

How can I read the Analysedfile_CSV so that the Analysed_List will have the same formatting as the Datafile_list?

Comment: I believe the issue is happening due to the way CSV file is written. If it is not mandatory to use CSV I would suggest you to save the analyzed_list a simple txt file with each line representing 1 file

Comment: You could be right, however, for testing purposes I've simply copied names from the datafile_list to analysed_csv to make sure reading works correctly and it doesn't. I'll try .txt in the meantime but would prefer to use excel due to processes

Comment: Can you share the how this particular analyzed_list csv file looks?

Comment: Not sure how to upload a screenshot so I'll try my best to format it a way that shows it well. Letters = columns, Numbers = Rows
A1 = ['Ant_10_Data.xlsx' 
A2 =  'Ant_11_Data.xlsx'
A3 =  'Ant_12_Data.xlsx'
B1 = Test